# GZipStream MacOS Catalina

Tags: c#, zip

When I try to zip my file, I get zip that does not contain any content (0 bytes), however the txt file does contain everything I need.

[image: Can not open zip (0 bytes) even though I use Archive Utility and Unarchiver and can open any zip file without any problems]

[![0 Bytes[image: Initial txt file 446 bytes]

My program:

```
            string startPath = "ResultsFile.txt";
            string zipPath = "ResultsFile.zip";

            using (FileStream r = new FileStream(startPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (FileStream w = File.Create(zipPath))
                {
                    using(GZipStream c = new GZipStream(w, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        r.CopyTo(c);
                        Console.WriteLine("Файл ахивирован!");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Main();
                    }    
                }
            }
```

Did anybody have similar problem using macOS Catalina with Visual Studio? Maybe There is mistake in my program? I need some help please.

Comment: ZIP and GZIP are not the same.  GZIP is compression.  There is a ZIP specification with different versions and not all tools support all versions.  Then there is optional modes that do not necessarily work between different tools.  Most of the time there are issues when somebody adds/deletes files to a ZIP after it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was due to Main() method called. When I remove it, everything works fine. However there is no mistake when I call Main() with Windows VisualStudio instead of MacOS with visual studio. The mystery that is yet to be solved...